# Check cross-browser compatibility

Tags: osx, web-development, web-browser, software-testing

I'm looking for a tool that gives me the ability to verify if my code works or not in other browsers (all?).

My problem is, I work with Macintosh (Mac / OS-X (Mavericks+)), and software like [Ghostlab](http://vanamco.com/ghostlab/) doesn't show me how the site works in Internet Explorer (for instance) nor old versions from browsers.

Requirements:

- Works in OS-X (preferable not a VM)
- Free or one payment only (not monthly)
- One single tool (I don't want to have a collection of *n* tools, each one for a specific browser/version)
- Test at least IE7+ (preferable IE6+), latest version of Chrome, Opera, Safari, Firefox. (Optional mobile.)

Items that must be able to be tested within the tool:

- HTML structure (I think, testing compatibility with CSS should do the job)
- JavaScript
- Forms (optional)

The tool should be noob friendly or have a good documentation.

Comment: There are a couple of websites like http://browsershots.org/ or https://browserling.com/ that allow you to preview website in many different browsers / versions. Would that suit your needs? Other ideas: http://mashable.com/2014/02/26/browser-testing-tools/

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt nope, They don't have internet explorer versions.

Comment: https://browserling.com/ (paid version) says to have MSIE 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0 10.0, 11.0 (but yeah, monthly payment :-/ )

Comment: Add: http://www.browserstack.com/

Answer (score 1):

I found the perfect application that meets all you needs <strike>except one, it only works in windows :(</strike> It's called BrowsEmAll (http://www.browseemall.com). I also found a website called netrender (http://netrenderer.com/). It only test's Internet Explorer versions 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6 or 5.5.

**Edit:**
According to CodeWeavers CrossOver Compatibility Center, they say that this program should work with no glitches whatsoever,

https://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name?app_id=13188

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of services which run your code across various environments, here are a few examples:

#### FOSS services

- [browsershots](http://browsershots.org) (most free browsers)

#### Paid services

- [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com) (many browsers and mobile devices)
- [browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/) (many browsers and mobile devices)

Answer (score 0):

Tools fall into two classes: live browser testing, and screenshots.

### Live browser testing

My best find so far (via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38715654) on StackOverflow):

- [CrossBrowserTesting](https://app.crossbrowsertesting.com)
- [Appetize](https://appetize.io/demo)

### Browser screenshot tools

There are a lot of them, just [search for "website snapshot service"](https://www.google.com/search?q=website%20snapshot%20service).

One of my favourites so far:

- [browshot.com](https://browshot.com/), offering screenshots with 30 different "real" desktop and mobile browsers (means, no simulators that differ in screen resolution only but actual browsers running on the specified devices)